# Get root privilege on SSH from WHM

Tags: ssh, root, cpanel, whm

I am a newbie for Web Host Manager(WHM). My client has 2 websites hosted on same server. He has given me the credentials for cPanels and WHM. Now when I want to change some setting or access any configuration file from SSH using the user created for a specific account, it blocks me to do so saying this user account does not have privilege to do so. Is there a way I can get a root user privilege?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to assign all root privileges to any normal cPanel account. If you have WHM access then login your WHM and enable shall access for that particular account which you want to access through SSH and after that you can login SSH with that user details.